# Ошибка при работе с перегрузкой оператора сложения

Tags: c++, ссылки, перегрузка-операторов, неопределённое-поведение

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <fstream> 
#include <sstream>

using namespace std; 

class MyVector
{
private:
    int* vec;
    int size; 

public:
    MyVector(int s = 0) { size = s; if (s != 0)
    {
        vec = new int[s];
    }
    }; //конструктор
    ~MyVector(); //деструктор
    void push_random();
    void show();
    void push();
    MyVector& operator+(MyVector&);
    MyVector& operator-(MyVector&);

};


MyVector::~MyVector() 
{       
    delete[] vec;
}

void MyVector::push_random()
{
    /*vec = new int[size];*/
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
        vec[i] = rand() % 25 + 1;
}

void MyVector::show()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        cout << vec[i]<<" "; 
}

void MyVector::push()
{
    /*vec = new int[size];*/
    int data; 
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cin >> data;
        vec[i] = data;
    }
}



MyVector & MyVector :: operator+( MyVector &vect)
{
    MyVector temp(vect.size);
    for (int i = 0; i < vect.size; i++)
    {
        temp.vec[i] = this->vec[i] + vect.vec[i];
    }
    return temp; 
}

MyVector & MyVector :: operator-(MyVector &vect)
{

    MyVector temp(vect.size);
    for (int i = 0; i < vect.size; i++)
    {
        temp.vec[i] = this->vec[i] - vect.vec[i];
    }
    return  temp;

}


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int value; int poz;
    string path = "1.txt";
    string path2 = "rez.txt";
    MyVector v1(5);
    v1.push_random();
    v1.show();
    cout << endl; 
    MyVector v2(5);
    v2.push();
    v2.show();
    MyVector rez = v1-v2;
    cout << endl; 
    rez.show();
    system("pause");

}
```

Не работает перегрузка операторов + и - , при выводе выдает мусор, хотя по откладчику считает все правильно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваши операторы возвращают ссылки на локальные объекты `temp`, которые (ссылки) становятся не действительны после выхода из операторов в виду удаления этих локальных объектов.

Например,

```
MyVector & MyVector :: operator+( MyVector &vect)
^^^^^^^^^^
{
    MyVector temp(vect.size);
    //...
    return temp; 
}
```

По крайней мере эти операторы следует объявить в классе как

```
friend const MyVector operator +( const MyVector &, const MyVector & );
friend const MyVector operator -( const MyVector &, const MyVector & );
```

Имейте также в виду, что дизайн вашего класса неудачный, так как вы можете объявить объекты класса MyVector с различным числом элементов в выделяемом динамически массиве. В этом случае вышеуказанные операторы не совсем ясно как определять.

Кроме того, поле `vec` не инициализируется в вашем конструкторе

```
MyVector(int s = 0) { size = s; if (s != 0)
{
    vec = new int[s];
}
}; //конструктор
```

когда `s` равно 0, что в общем случае может привести к неопределенному поведению.

И вы должны по крайней мере определить конструктор копирования и оператор присваивания.

Ниже приведена минимальная демонстрационная программа, которая показывает, как эти операторы могут быть объявлены и определены.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

class MyVector
{
private:
    size_t size; 
    int *vec;

public:
    MyVector( size_t s = 0 ) : size( s ), vec( s == 0 ? nullptr : new int[s] {} ) 
    {
    }

    MyVector( const MyVector &v ) : size( v.size ), vec( v.size == 0 ? nullptr : new int[v.size] {} ) 
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < size; i++ ) vec[i] = v.vec[i];
    }

    ~MyVector()
    {
        delete [] vec;
    }

    friend const MyVector operator+( const MyVector &, const MyVector & );
    friend const MyVector operator-( const MyVector &, const MyVector & );
};

const MyVector operator+( const MyVector &a, const MyVector &b )
{
    MyVector temp( std::max( a.size, b.size ) );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < a.size; i++ )
    {
        temp.vec[i] = a.vec[i];
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < b.size; i++ )
    {
        temp.vec[i] += b.vec[i];
    }
}

const MyVector operator-( const MyVector &a, const MyVector &b )
{
    MyVector temp( std::max( a.size, b.size ) );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < a.size; i++ )
    {
        temp.vec[i] = a.vec[i];
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < b.size; i++ )
    {
        temp.vec[i] -= b.vec[i];
    }
}

int main() 
{
    MyVector a( 10 );
    MyVector b( 10 );

    MyVector c = a + b;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: если объявлять, как их как дружественные, то возникает ошибка., что данный класс не члена operator+

Comment: @Диана Объявление этих операторов как дружественные функции не ведет к ошибке. Ваша ошибка - это результат другого неверного кода.

Comment: так как лучше поступить в моем случае?:с

Comment: @Диана Как я написал в своем ответе.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за помощь!